# How to parse json response from twitter

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, twitter

So I'm doing a request like this: https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name=twitterapi&count=3

Now, I'm using jQuery, and I'm trying to display the data like this:

```
  success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {

    if(data)
    {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      $("#at .tweet-message").html(data.text);
    };
```

I want to display 3 tweets, what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing the index when referencing data array elements (apart from some braces):

```
success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {

    if(data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
           $("#at .tweet-message").html(data[i].text); //here
        }
    }
}
```

**edit**

It shows only one tweet because you're using `html()` instead of, for example, `append()`. You substitute the element content in each iteration.

Comment: Good not just referring to `$.each`

Comment: It displays only one tweet not all 3 :(

Comment: @Uffo Are you familiar with `console.log`? Then try to log `data`

Answer (score 1):

Another way by chaching `data.length`. Just extented [soulcheck's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12971708/887539)

```
success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
    var i = 0,
        len = data ? data.length : 0;

    for ( ; i < len; i++ ) {
        $("#at .tweet-message").html(data[i].text);
    }
}
```

---

`len = data ? data.length : 0` means:

```
if ( data ) {
    len = data.length;
}
else {
    len = 0;
}
```